# The meaning of 内 with other Kanjis

Tags: grammar, meaning, newspaper-grammar

Konnichiwa , I found this sentence on the news recently :
"政府内には、「信教の自由を脅かしかねない」との慎重論もあるが、宗教法人法に基づく調査が実施されれば、初めての事になる。"

- And I can't figure out whether "政府内には" means "inside of the government" (as referring to  the group that governs the country) or maybe (as referring to the place where politics for the country are done)
- Also I quite don't grasp at 100 % the meaning of "事" in "初めての事になる"

Comment: Why don’t you translate it as “**within** the government”?

Answer (score 0):

[政府](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E5%9B%BD%E6%94%BF%E5%BA%9C) :

> 広義には立法府、司法府、行政府などの統治機構を総称し、狭義には内閣および内閣の統轄する中央省庁（官僚機構）のみを指す[3]
>
> in the broad sense, collectively refers to the governing organization, including legislative, judiciary, administrative bodies; in the narrow sense, it refers only to the cabinet and ministries (bureaucratic system).
>
> <sub>(I don't know the terminology is completely correct.)</sub>

I suppose here it means the latter. Hence it says that there are bureaucrats concerned about freedom of religion. It is possible that 政府 refers to the cabinet and there are  concerned ministers though.

事 is just *thing*, or maybe *event* is easier to understand - 初めての事 means *the thing (that happens) for the first time*.

Comment: I think the point was that the sentence does _not_ use 政府, but actually uses **政府内** instead, and it is the 内 part that is not understood.  I'm not an expert, but I would interpret this to probably mean "(some people) within the government"